# Unclear Information about NSData - Objective C/Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the following lines of code to download and save an html page ::

```
NSURL *goo = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:goo];
```

What is actually contained in this data ?? Does it also contain CSS files and images that are displayed on the google homepage ?? I tried to NSLog this data but the result was not useful. I mean I could no tunderstand the result displayed in the gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert `NSData` to `NSString` and then `NSLog` it you will see what actually data contains

```
NSString* dataStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"%@",dataStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The contained data is just what you get as a response to the request so html only

Answer (score 0):

As you can find here:

[NSData Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

NSData is just an array of bytes you use to store some info, in your case, the HTML response